# Fire and forget pattern over TCP, is it good to connect, send and disconnect?

Tags: design-patterns, tcp, fire-and-forget

I was wondering how the fire and forget pattern is implemented over TCP. I think that the three steps are **connect**, **send** message and **disconnect** but what keeps me thinking about how it is really implemented is the overhead related to the three-way-handshake. Maybe it is implemented with a persistent connection due to this overhead? I don't think so but I need some clarification about this.

Comment: if it's persistent, then by definition you aren't "forgetting".

Comment: @MarcB I know, I know, just want someone to assert my question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is a larger overhead: Creating a new socket each time or maintaining a single socket for data transfer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541889/which-is-a-larger-overhead-creating-a-new-socket-each-time-or-maintaining-a-sin)